# External stylesheets with ConvertTo-Html not working?

Tags: html, css, powershell

I have a lot of webpages I produce using PowerShell. It would be great to make them all nice and fluffy with some CSS. If I use internal CSS all is good. It would save time and space if there was a central CSS I could use but testing the external style sheet I get no style output at all.

```bsh
$Style = "
<style>

<link rel = 'stylesheet'
    type = 'text/css'
    href = 'myStyle.css' />

</style>
<h2>hello</h2>
<p>hello</p>
"

ConvertTo-Html -Title "Hello" -Body $Style | Out-File test.htm
```

My style sheet contains

```css
h2 {
    color: #FFFF33;
    text-align: center;
    font: italic 200% fantasy;
}

p {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font: italic 200% fantasy;
}
```

Is it possible to use external style sheets with the `ConverTo-Html` cmdlet?

Comment: Remove the <style> tags.

Comment: `-Body $Style` -> `-CssUri 'myStyle.css'`